# List words from file in alphabetical order in python

Tags: python-2.7

I've just started learning python. One task I have to complete is write a code that will take a user submitted text file and list the words in the file alphabetically.

My code.

```
f=open(raw_input("What file would you like to import?"))
for word in f:
    print(sorted(word))
```

This doesn't list the words in alphabetically but lists the letter in the word in alphabetical order.

eg. instead of human, `['\n', 'a', 'h', 'm', 'n', 'u']` is outputted.

EDIT

The words in the text file are on separate lines like:

```
human  
dog  
cat 
etc..
```

The output looks like:

```
['\n', 'a', 'h', 'm', 'n', 'u']
['\n', 'd', 'g', 'o']
etc..
```

however I need the output to be:
   aardvark
   cat
   cow
   dog
   ect...

Comment: Some more info would be good like are the words departed by spaces or new line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that `for word in f` loops over the lines in the file, and if there is one word per line, then `sorted(word)` will sort the elements (letters) of just that word.

Instead, just do `sorted(f)` to sort the lines (i.e. words) in the file.

Note that this will include the line end character. Use `sorted(map(str.strip, f))` to remove that, by applying the `strip` function to each of the lines/words. Alternatively, you can also use `sorted(f.read().split())` to strip the content of the file at any whitespace character. This will also work when there are multiple words per line.